# PHP Accessing SimpleXMLElement Object array keys

Tags: php, simplexml

In the following SimpleXMLElement Object `$results`, I would like to remove the element with ID `13011146` from the TEST array. I'm not sure how to properly access the array key with value `1`, so I'm using a counter `$i`, but that gives me an error `Node no longer exists`, pointing to the foreach line.

**TL;DR**: How do you unset `$result->TEST[1]` ?

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [TEST] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 13011145
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 13011146
                        )

                )
        )

)
```

PHP:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($results->TEST as $key => $value) {
    if( (string)$value['ID'] == 13011146 ) {
        unset($results->TEST[$i]);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the `XML` for main `SimpleXMLElement Object`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($results->TEST->children() as $key => $value) { 
    $attributes = $value->attributes();
    foreach($attributes as $a => $b) {
        if (( (string)$a == 'ID' ) && ( (string)$b == '13011146' )) {    
            unset($results->TEST[$key]);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, misread your structure: Should be fixed by the call to children() - see edited version

Comment: Now we don't even enter in the first foreach loop :s If I remove children() then a match if found for $a and $b but again the value of $key is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$node = $results->children();
unset($node[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

a more elegant way; it gives you the same results without using $attributes[ '@attributes' ] :

```
$attributes = current($element->attributes());
```

For specific key/value pair, we can use like:

```
$attributes = current($value->attributes()->NAME);
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
   foreach ($sxe->children() as $child){
      foreach($child as $key=>$item){
         echo $key.': '.$item.'<br />';
      }
   }
```